# Javascript scope and new array()

Tags: javascript, json

I know I am violating scope rules in my javascript code, and I am pretty sure I know what's wrong.  I just do not understand the rules that make what I am doing wrong or how to fix it.

I am creating an application that has a photo gallery. The system displays 9 photos at once.  When the user wants to see new photos, he can click an arrow on the right side of the screen.  This action queries the server for more photos, which are subsequently returned as a json list. If the user clicks an arrow on the left side of the screen, he can view previously seen photos.  For this reason, it makes sense to cache all of the photo URLs client side.

This caching is done in a global variable (I know it's bad, but I do not understand JS and did not know how else to make it work) named photoData.  photoData is a 2 dimensional array containing the set of photos where a particualar photo appeared (basically how many times the user clicked the right arrow before reaching this photo) and all the photo urls that appeared in that set. I am running into an issue where the photos will populate photoData correctly in my GetNewPhotos() function, but they leave the array after the function goes out of scope.

Before I post my code, let me say that any criticism is welcome.  I started with javascript 2 days ago and am not great with it. Fortunately, jQuery does most of the work.

Here is my code:

```
var photoData = new Array();
var currentPhotoSet = 1;
var maxPhotoSet = 1;

//I originally tried using a closure to avoid global variables and it wasn't working properly, but this is still lingering here.
(function() 
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //Irrelevant functions removed for clarity's sake
        GetNewPhotos();
    });
})();

function GetNewPhotos()
{
    $("#right-arrow").click(function(event) 
    {
        currentPhotoSet++
        if (currentPhotoSet <= maxPhotoSet)
        {
          // Load photos from cache
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/match/",
                 data: {"arrow" : "right", "currentPhotoSet" : currentPhotoSet},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(jsonObject) 
                 { 
                    photoData[currentPhotoSet] = new Array();
                    photoData[currentPhotoSet] = jsonObject;
                 }
            });
        }
        SwapOnscreenPhotos(currentPhotoSet)
    });
}

function SwapOnscreenPhotos(currentPhotoSet)
{
    $("#photo-list img").each(function(index) 
    { 
        $(this).attr("src", photoData[currentPhotoSet][index+1]); 
    }); 
}
```

So the new urls appear in photoData after doing the AJAX query, but when we get to SwapOnscreenPhotos, they have disappeared, the added array no longer appears inside photoData.  I think this has something to do with this line photoData[currentPhotoSet] = new Array();

Does declaring the array in this scope mean it goes out of scope when I leave this function?  That is weird because this data belongs to the photoData global variable. If I did need to declare new arrays outside of this function, how in the world would I do this? I cannot know at compile time how many times the AJAX request will be called.

As a side note, if anyone has commentary on my decision to do rendering of the HTML client side as opposed to server side, I would love to hear it.  I was debating between sending back only the required urls in JSON vs. sending the entire DOM element that contains the images and then caching those instead.  I know javascript is slow, so the latter choice might be better.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `ajax` is asynchronous. ` SwapOnscreenPhotos(currentPhotoSet)` does not wait for the data from server and runs as soon as `#right-arrow` is clicked. Try putting this on `success` event of ajax.

Comment: very good point! I will try that.  I made a newbie mistake.

Comment: _"Does declaring the array in this scope mean it goes out of scope when I leave this function?"_ No. In fact you're not actually using that array at all. The line `photoData[currentPhotoSet] = new Array();` is not needed because the next line `photoData[currentPhotoSet] = jsonObject;` doesn't add to that new array, it changes `photoData[currentPhotoSet]` so that it now references `jsonObject` instead of that new array. (Unrelated tip: declare new empty arrays with `[]` rather than `new Array()`, e.g., `var someArray = [];`.)